# How to implement IServiceCollection DI to ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I have an old MVC Application which is written in Framework 4.7.2 and I have to use a Service which is already on .NET Standard 2.0.

I try to use dependency injection and from a .NET Core project I can register this ServiceCollection in the startup file. But how can I do this on a project which is framework 4.7.2?

Can I use IServiceCollection in this older Framework? When yes, how can i implement this?

thanks

Comment: Quick and easy way would be going into Application_OnStart in the global asax